# Correct way to populate select box using Prototype-JS

Tags: prototypejs

I would like to populate a select box with data fetched by ajax.

The initial HTML code looks like:

```
<select id="myid" name="myname">
</select>
```

I need to avoid `innerHTML` and other such workarounds. I tried using `appendChild` but it did not seem to work.
I am really new to prototype, so I really dont know how to go about it.

Comment: How did you try `appendChild` (what type of elements to which parent)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanted to add all members of a self-created object as key-value pairs to a `select` element, you could do that this way:

```
var data = {
  a: 'Peter',
  b: 'Paul',
  c: 'Mary'
};

$('mySelect').update($H(data).map(function(o) {
  return '<option value="' + o.key + '">' + o.value + '</option>';
}).join(''));
​
```

You find a [jsFiddle of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Udtyp/).

The basic idea behind the code is, that you create your `option` elements from the given data object, by transforming every one of them into a string. That is done by the [map](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Enumerable/prototype/collect/) method.

The `$H` will transform the data object into a Prototype `Hash` object, which comes in handy here, as it will pass a `{ key, value }` object to the first parameter of it's map invocation.

After transforming all elements to Strings, you just have to `join` them by an empty String (or whatever non-HTML code you like, \n would do as well) to be able to use them for the `update` method.

To be honest, [Element#update](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/update/) uses `innerHTML` so that is actually not a workaround. It's just one way to do it.